# How to make the addition of new maps side by side horizontally?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Angular 5.2.0. I have a loop with the addition of a new entry. Entries are added to "cards". But the problem is that they are now added vertically. And how can I make it so that they are added all along the horizontally by about 5 "cards" in a row as a new record is added ie 6 was transferred to a new row.

html and all css on the cards: :

```css
.card{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px 0;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    border-radius: $border-radius-base;
    color: $mdb-card-body-text;
    background: $mdb-card-body-background;

    .card-height-indicator {
        margin-top: 100%;
    }

    .title{
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .card-image {
        height: 60%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;

        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        border-radius: $border-radius-large;

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: $border-radius-large;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .card-title {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 15px;
            left: 15px;
            color: $mdb-card-image-headline;
            font-size: $font-size-h4;
            text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
        }
    }

    .category:not([class*="text-"]){
        color: $gray-color;
    }
    .card-content{
        padding: 15px 20px;

        .category{
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    }

    .card-header{
        @include shadow-big();
        margin: -20px $margin-base 0;
        border-radius: $border-radius-base;
        padding: $padding-base;
        background-color: $gray-color;

        .title{
            color: $white-color;
        }
        .category{
            margin-bottom: 0;
            color: rgba($white-color, .62);
        }

        &.card-chart{
            padding: 0;
            min-height: 160px;

            + .content{
                h4{
                    margin-top: 0;
                }
            }
        }

        .ct-label{
            color: rgba($white-color, .7);
        }
        .ct-grid{
            stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        }
        .ct-series-a .ct-point,
        .ct-series-a .ct-line,
        .ct-series-a .ct-bar,
        .ct-series-a .ct-slice-donut{
            stroke: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        }
        .ct-series-a .ct-slice-pie,
        .ct-series-a .ct-area{
            fill: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
        }

    }

    .chart-title{
        position: absolute;;
        top: 25px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;

        h3{
            margin: 0;
            color: $white-color;
        }

        h6{
            margin: 0;
            color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);
        }

    }

    .card-footer{
        margin: 0 20px 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;

        .content{
            display: block;
        }

        div{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .author{
            color: $gray-color;
        }
        .stats{
            line-height: 22px;
            color: $gray-color;
            font-size: $font-size-small;

            .material-icons{
                position: relative;
                top: 4px;
                font-size: $font-paragraph;
            }
        }

        h6{
            color: $gray-color;
        }

    }

    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .category{
        .material-icons{
            position: relative;
            top: 6px;
            line-height: 0;
        }
    }

    .category-social{
        .fa{
            font-size: 24px;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: -4px;
            top: 2px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    }

    .author{
        .avatar{
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        a{
            color: $black-color;
            text-decoration: none;

            .ripple-container{
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }

    .table{
        margin-bottom: 0;

        tr:first-child td{
            border-top: none;
        }
    }

    [data-background-color="purple"]{
        background: linear-gradient(60deg, $purple-400, $purple-600);
        @include shadow-big-color($brand-primary);
    }

    [data-background-color="blue"]{
        background: linear-gradient(60deg, $blue-900, $blue-900);
        @include shadow-big-color($brand-info);
    }

    [data-background-color="green"]{
        background: linear-gradient(60deg, $green-400, $green-600);
        @include shadow-big-color($brand-success);
    }

    [data-background-color="orange"]{
        background: linear-gradient(60deg, $orange-400, $orange-600);
        @include shadow-big-color($brand-warning);
    }

    [data-background-color="red"]{
        background: linear-gradient(60deg, $red-400, $red-600);
        @include shadow-big-color($brand-danger);
    }

    [data-background-color]{
        color: $white-color;

        a{
            color: $white-color;
        }
    }
}

.card-stats{
    .title{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .card-header{
        float: left;
        text-align: center;

        i{
            font-size: 36px;
            line-height: 56px;
            width: 56px;
            height: 56px;
        }
    }
    .card-content{
        text-align: right;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

}

.card-nav-tabs{
    .header-raised{
        margin-top: -$margin-base * 2;
    }
    .nav-tabs{
        background: transparent;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .nav-tabs-title{
        float: left;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
}

.card-plain{
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;

    .card-header{
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .content{
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .card-image{
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: $border-radius-base;

        img{
            border-radius: $border-radius-base;
        }
    }
}

.iframe-container{
    margin: 0 -20px 0;

    iframe{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 0;
        @include shadow-big();
    }
}

.card-profile,
.card-testimonial{
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;

    .btn-just-icon.btn-raised{
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right: 6px;
    }

    .card-avatar{
        max-width: 130px;
        max-height: 130px;
        margin: -50px auto 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;

        @include shadow-big();

        & + .content{
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
    }

    &.card-plain{
        .card-avatar{
            margin-top: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div *ngFor="let note of notes" >
    <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
      <i class="material-icons">store</i>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content" >
      <p class="category">{{note.name}} </p>
     </div>
     <div class="card-footer">
       <div class="stats">
         <button class="button-save" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>    
         <button class="button-trash" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>     
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your snippet output what you intended it to be? It looks like there aren't any cards.

Comment: @Keara Here's how it looks now https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/7/23/a857e98361450b587f72bfe0687376f9-full.png

Comment: I see. The code you posted definitely doesn't show that when it's run inside the snippet, I'm not sure whether that matters or not.

Comment: @Keara it will not show, there is a snippet cycle installed that does not support Snippet

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Just wanted to check that there wasn't just some small issue. :) Just a tiny nitpicky side note: it might be a good idea to put the code just as plain code instead of a snippet, to avoid any possible confusion about what the output looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the *ngFor on the following element

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let note of notes">
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let note of notes">
      <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
        <i class="material-icons">store</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="category">{{note.name}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <button class="button-save"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
          <button class="button-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let note of notes">
      <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
        <i class="material-icons">store</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="category">{{note.name}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <button class="button-save"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
          <button class="button-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let note of notes">
      <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
        <i class="material-icons">store</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="category">{{note.name}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <button class="button-save"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
          <button class="button-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let note of notes">
      <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
        <i class="material-icons">store</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="category">{{note.name}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <button class="button-save"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
          <button class="button-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let note of notes">
      <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
        <i class="material-icons">store</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="category">{{note.name}} </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <button class="button-save"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
          <button class="button-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See full page snippet to see the results(as the results will be seen after sm screens)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the Bopotstrap grid structure to incorporate 5 columns in a row. Try using the following structure, you will be able to get what you want.

```css
.col.col-2 {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-2">
      1 columns
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
      2 columns
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
      3 columns
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
      4 columns
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
      5 columns
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
      6 columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not helped, https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/7/23/a857e98361450b587f72bfe0687376f9-full.png

Comment: Please add your working snippet, include static HTML and CSS. Will be easier to do formatting.

Comment: he has already been added. you ignore, just that I have a loop set html *ngFor="let note of notes"

Comment: I think @Charu means that it will be much easier for folks to troubleshoot if we have an easy way to run your code and see exactly what you are seeing. Since snippets aren't able to run your code properly, maybe you could try putting your code in a JSFiddle and posting the link here?